# Find $f_x$ in terms of $f$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider $f(x, y) =  g(x^2, y^2)$
>
> > Find $f_x(x, y)$ in terms of $f(x, y)$ or $g(x^2, y^2)$ or $g_x$ of $g_y$ if any of them is possible.

I am not sure how to apply the rules here, but say it was a one variable function like

$f(x) = g(x^2)$ then I can easily use the chain rule on the RHS and get $f'(x) = g'(x^2) 2x$, but how do I apply it with 2 dimensional variables?

Comment: Precisely the same way!! But with partial derivatives.

Comment: Check out the section on higher dimensions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

We have $$f (x,y )=g (u,v) $$ then
$$df=f_xdx+f_ydy=$$
$$dg=g_udu+g_vdv $$

with $$du=2xdx+0dy $$ thus by identification

> $$f_x(x,y)=2xg_x (x^2,y^2) $$

Comment: Don't you mean $f_x$ instead of $f_x'$?

Comment: @OussamaBoussif partial derivative with respect to x.

Comment: Oh so both notations are equivalent?